# Dynamic datasource config in wildfly

Tags: java, datasource, wildfly-10

I have a wildfly 10 (Java + Spring) project. I have a requirement to dynamically inject the datasource (mysql) config details to wildfly. But since wildfly depends on the standalone xml file at startup, and needs it before even the java beans are created, the only way I've found so far is to inject is by setting env vars (by running some other program/script to fetch the configs before wildfly starts). Is there any other better option?
Is it possible to do this through the same java application itself, ignoring the xml and set the right config? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

## `DataSource` object via JNDI

Externalize your JDBC connection details by using [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) to access a [naming/directory server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) to obtain an object implementing the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface.

With a `DataSource` object in hand, call `getConnection` to obtain a [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html).

See tutorial by Oracle, [*Connecting with DataSource Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html).